# Countifs in Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery

How can I write below formula in Power Query.

=countifs(A:A,A1,B:B,”In scope”)

Lets say Col A has Id numbers(can be repeated) and Col B has either Not in Scope or In Scope values only

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vitcf.png)

Comment: Your sample makes no sense to me. There are two "Not in Scopes" for ID#2, you have counts of one for them.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"ID", "Scope"}, {{"data", each _, type table [ID=number, Scope=text]}, {"count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"ID", "Scope"}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "data", {"ID", "Scope"}, {"ID", "Scope"})
in  #"Expanded data"
```

or

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"ID", "Scope"}, {{"count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}})
in #"Grouped Rows"
```

Comment: The groupby would not give me the In Scope count in that corresponding line for that particular ID, I have attached a snippet and the desired output too

Comment: edited sample answer

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
Count of In Scope =
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( YourTableName[ID] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( YourTableName, YourTableName[ID] ),
    YourTableName[Scope] = "In Scope"
)
```

[image: In Scope]

or if you want a brief table try this :

Modelling ---> New Table

```
In Scope List =
CALCULATETABLE (
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE ( YourTableName, YourTableName[ID], YourTableName[Scope] ),
        "Count", CALCULATE ( COUNT ( YourTableName[ID] ) )
    ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( YourTableName, YourTableName[ID] ),
    YourTableName[Scope] = "In Scope"
)
```

[image: brief]